# TextBlob NaiveBayesClassifier Always Returns 1

Tags: python, data-science, textblob

I am working on a project for a data science class that scrapes popular news sites based on a user-defined search term and returns how much each site leans conservative/liberal. I've run into an issue using TextBlob where my NaiveBayesClassifier always returns 1.

My training set includes 28 articles labeled 'conservative', 26 labeled 'liberal'. After instantiating my classifier (cl), I run

```
print(cl)
print(cl.show_informative_features(10))
```

which returns

[image]

Since there is such a large bias in the use of the term "restrictions", I use it as a simple test:

```
print(cl.prob_classify('restrictions').prob('conservative')  # 1.0
```

To my surprise, the term is categorized as 'conservative' with a 100% probability! In fact, every word, phrase, article, etc. I try to classify returns with a 100% probability of being conservative.

Could anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong? There is a "None" returned by cl.show_informative_features - does this have any meaning?

EDIT:
I'm trying to make a smaller example, but for now my GitHub repo for this is at https://github.com/jpbic/news_scraper. Just run "text_analysis.py". The CSV data used to train the classifier is in "data/news_scraper_data.csv".

Comment: Are you familiar with [Laplace smoothing](http://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/slides/7_NB.pdf#page=31)? This sounds like a situation where the word "restrictions" was only observed in "conservative" documents.

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes Just counted the occurrences of "restrictions" for both conservative and liberal categories - {'conservative': 1, 'liberal': 20}. "restrictions" occurs FAR more often in training data labeled "liberal".

Comment: Interesting, probably not that then. Edit to add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and maybe someone will see the problem.